# Laravel vuejs axios response.data I can not display data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axis

I am new, maybe I am asking simple question, but I don't find an answer. But I very need this solution. I try to take data from github repo issues by using rest api, but I can not to display that. I dont know why, i tryed to find solutions, but I dont find a correct answer.

My Laravel Ilist.vue file:

```html
<template>
    <h1>List</h1>
<ul>
    <li v-for="issue in info">

    {{ issue.url }}:
    </li>
</ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                info: null
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            axios
                .get('https://api.github.com/repos/waffleio/waffle.io/issues')
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data.bpi);
                    this.info = response.data.bpi;
                })
        }
    }
</script>
```

But I get only this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyQDl.png)

My blade template:

```html
<!doctype html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- CSRF Token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            <div id="app">
                <ilist></ilist>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My assets/js/app.js file:

```js
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

let axios = require('axios');
Vue.component('ilist', require('./components/Ilist.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

I changed in assets/js/bootstrap.js

```js
// let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
//
// if (token) {
//     window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
// } else {
//     console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
// }

window.axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

I want to display https://api.github.com/repos/waffleio/waffle.io/issues data in to ul,li list. What I should to do? 
Then I just install fresh Larave I run these commands: npm install, npm run watch.

Comment: update `this.info = response.data.bpi;` to `this.info = response;`

Comment: you get an array as response.data. That's why response.data.bpi is undefined

Comment: Ok. I changed Ilist.vue: 

mounted () { axios .get('api.github.com/repos/waffleio/waffle.io/issues') .then((response) => { console.log(response); this.info = response; }) }

 But still I get blank screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `this.info = response.data.bpi;` by `this.info = response.data;`

I've tested and it works.

If you have a blank screen, it means that you have a different problem.
Open your console and check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked https://api.github.com/repos/waffleio/waffle.io/issues and haven't found any `response.data.bpi` so replace `response.data.bpi` with `response`

Comment: Ok. I changed Ilist.vue:

mounted () {
            axios
                .get('https://api.github.com/repos/waffleio/waffle.io/issues')
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.info = response;
                })
        }

But still I get blank screen

Answer (score 0):

You console log `response.data.bpi` which is undefined. So instead of that console log just `response`. Then you can find a way to find the `bpi` if there is a thing called `bpi`